# Django form not showing except for submit button

Tags: python, django

I'm having this issue where the django form isn't showing up on the webpage. The only thing that shows up is the submit button. I cannot figure out the issue.

Views.py

```
class NewThreadView(CreateView):
    model = Thread
    form_class = NewThreadForm
    template_name = 'thread/newthread.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(NewThreadView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
```

forms.py

```
class NewThreadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Thread
        fields = ('name', 'body', 'author', 'thread_forum')

        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter title'}),
            'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'author': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'value': '', 'id': 'author', 'type': 'hidden'}),
            'thread_forum': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'hidden'}),
        }
```

newthread.html

```
<div class="form-group">
     <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="thread_submit">Create Thread</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your context isn't returned so there isn't anything for the template to render. You need to return the context;

```
class NewThreadView(CreateView):
    model = Thread
    form_class = NewThreadForm
    template_name = 'thread/newthread.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(NewThreadView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        return context
```

Comment: facepalm, I can't believe I forgot something so simple, worked like a charm. Thanks, champ!

Comment: @TaziamomaAbraham problems are always (mostly) more simple than we first think!! Can you mark this as accepted as well so that people know it's answered?

Comment: I will, I have to wait 4 minutes tho.

Comment: Here it does not make much sense to override `get_context_data` I think, since we only return the result of a `super()` call.

Comment: What would be an alternative? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Just remove the function from your class. If all it does is call super then the parent class will handle it for you